# How do you claim free retcon tokens?

Tags: champions-online

[Part of the release notes](http://www.champions-online.com/release-notes?page=2) for a recent Champions Online patch states that due to power changes, a global retcon token is made available for each account, claimable in the Powerhouse. I'm a bit new to this game, and I'm having a bit of trouble finding exactly how to claim this token. I've spoken to the NPCs in the Powerhouse, but the only option I see is for purchasing a retcon, not using a free one.

How do I claim this thing? Or am I not eligible because I'm a somewhat new subscriber?

Comment: Ah, nevermind; figured it out. You have to be at least level 21 to use it. Serves me right for panicking, I suppose.

Comment: If you have figured out the answer on your own, could you please post your solution as an answer to your question and then accept it? Though there's a 2 day grace period before you accept your own answer, it will help us to not have a seemingly unanswered question floating around. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to be at least level 21 to use it; I wasn't at the time.